# What is the best way to determine URL for local/staging/production?

Tags: asp.net

For local testing the url is something like:
http://localhost:29234/default.aspx

For staging, the app is in a virtual directory:
http://stage/OurApp/default.aspx

For production, it's the root
http://www.ourcompany.com/default.aspx

However, sometimes we need to do a redirect to a particular directory.  We don't always know exactly where we are at.

So, how would I do a redirect to say /subdir1/mypage.aspx?

**MORE INFO**

I neglected an important item.  This url is sent back to the browser so that some javascript code can perform the redirect. (Odd, I know).  So a regular ResolveUrl("~/pagename.aspx") won't give the full info...

**UPDATE 2**
I ended up with the following, which seems to work across the board...  It looks a little ugly though.

```
StringBuilder buildUrl = new StringBuilder(@"http://");
buildUrl.Append(Request.Url.Host);
if (Request.Url.Port != 80) {
    buildUrl.Append(":");
    buildUrl.Append(Request.Url.Port.ToString());
}
buildUrl.Append(this.ResolveUrl("~/Pages/Customers.aspx"));
buildUrl.Append(String.Format("?AccountId={0}&tabName=Tab2&primaryCustomerId={1}", acctId, custId));
```

Comment: I'm hoping this is a closed environment where JavaScript is 'known good' and always enabled?

Irrespective, I'm not seeing what the problem is - are you trying to determine what environment you're running on based on the current hostname/URI, or merely having issues with using redirects that are relative to the base web directory.

Comment: Are you redirecting to within the same web application, or are you redirecting to a different virtual directory / web app?

Comment: Completely internal application.  Same app.

Comment: If it's within the same app, why can't you just use the relative paths like I mentioned below?

Comment: just fyi - this does not account for different protocols ex: https, ftp...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When paths start diverging between different environments, and you cannot bring any sanity to the situation, it's time to start puttin' paths in the web.config.

It's not a cure for inconsistent file paths, but it'll make your *code* consistent and you won't have to worry about having "let's figure out where i am" logic.

Comment: I thought about this.  Other than the code I added to my question, this is probably the best answer.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The tilde is a shortcut for [HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainappvirtualpath.aspx) ([more](http://www.aspnetpro.com/newsletterarticle/2003/11/asp200311kd_l/asp200311kd_l.asp))

```
~/subdir1/mypage.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

If the subdir1 is a directory within your web application, you can use a relative link (subdir1/mypage.aspx instead of /subdir/mypage.aspx -- note the lack of the first forward slash).  This way, it won't matter where your application is because the links will be relative to the current page.

Comment: When I send the url back without the forward slash, it thinks that it's starting from the current directory.  Meaning, IF my page is in /sub3 then not using the forward slash results in /sub3/subdir1/mypage.aspx... which is the wrong location.

Comment: So, then send it back with the two dots (..) to make it go up one directory.  ../subdir1/mypage.aspx.  I just prefer to let the web browser / server handle path location instead of trying to construct the path myself in code.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion is you can use the BASE tag for the page which can be the root. by using this, all your relative paths will be resolved based on BASE path.

Answer (score 0):

**General Advice**

I recommend storing the path in your settings.  There are reasons why some of our projects need various paths and urls, and we can't always get away with using the tilde (~).

**Our Strategy**

In our projects here at Inntec, our web.config contains a database connection string and a variable saying what the environment is - Production, Staging, Development, etc.

Then, in the database, we've got a set of variables for each environment, and there's a nice class that strongly types the settings and pulls/caches the right setting for the current environment. So in our code we can say: Settings.AppUrl and everything just works.

We use Redgate's Sql Data Compare to sync the settings across all instances (so each environments always has the settings for all environments), and there are unit tests that make sure each environment has a complete batch of settings.

That's one way to do it... So far it has worked really well for us.